# How can I reload a view controller once I have signed into Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, master-detail

I have a Master Detail app in which I am storing a boolean in NSUserDefaults which controls access of the app. Once a user signs in with Parse, I update this value.

However, the problem is that when I go back to the Master View Controller, it does not run the ViewDidLoad code in which I check for the access variable and does not update.

Is there a way to reload a view controller programmatically or could there be another solution?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: you are trying to reload the viewcontroller with what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just check if the value of the Bool Variable has changed, and if it does then run the `viewDidLoad()` method.

To check if a value is changed in a Bool run the `willSet` method as such:

```
var myBool: Bool = Bool() {

      willSet {

            println("the value of the variable has changed")
            viewDidLoad()

      }

}
```

this code that I wrote automatically checks if the value of the variable changes, and if it does then it will run the code in the `willSet` method. in this case it will run the viewDidLoad() statement again and print: "the value of the variable has changed".

I am assuming that the `viewDidLoad()`, when refreshed, will reset the content settings and make sure the user has access to whatever he/she needs access to.

Also if you are just having trouble reloading the `viewDidLoad()` method than just run the `viewDidAppear` method:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    viewDidLoad()

    //OR JUST RELOAD THE CONTENT SETTINGS
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the best answer I have seen. I'd upvote it twice if I could